# Am I correct that this async-await example doesn't do anything useful?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm looking at a piece of code that is like (I'm writing the equivalent, not directly copy-pasting)

```
public virtual async Task<Something> SomeMethodAsync(string s)
{
   string uri = String.Format(stuff, param);
   Something something;
   HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
   if(responseMsg.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      response = await responseMsg.Content.ReadAsAsync<Something>(blah);
   else
      throw new CreateException(String.Format(problemo));
   return response;
}
```

that is called like

```
    public virtual Something GetSomething(string id)
    {
        return GetOrderAsync(id).Result;
    }
```

I'm wondering whether my suspicion about whether this does anything helpful is correct.

Since the method

```
    public virtual Something GetSomething(string id)
    {
        return SomeMethodAsync(id).Result;
    }
```

does not await `SomeMethodAsync`, that means when the line `HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);` is reached and control is yielded back to `GetSomething`, there is no independent work that can be done in the meantime.

Furthermore, having the two awaits

```
   HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
   if(responseMsg.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      response = await responseMsg.Content.ReadAsAsync<Something>(blah);
```

does not accomplish anything because the 2nd is dependent on the result of the first.

Am I correct about that?

Comment: What's the context for the code - console app, Web API, Windows Forms, etc.? There are subtle (and sometimes not-so-subtle) differences in how async/await works in each environment.

Comment: You're correct in that the code will block on the `.Result` call (I guess it's because the HTTP API only exposes async functions but the calling code wasn't prepared to handle that, which is bad), but having two `await` points is perfectly sensible.

Comment: This is a good reference on this subject: [Asynchronous Programming with async and await (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx)

Comment: [Exposing synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods is an anti-pattern.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/)

Answer (score 3):

It's worse than just being useless, it's actively harmful: in fact, the following code

```
public virtual Something GetSomething(string id)
{
    return SomeMethodAsync(id).Result;
}
```

will deadlock in several environments (e.g. Windows Forms) - specifically, it'll deadlock in any environment where you have a synchronization context. That's why Stephen Cleary *et. al.* strongly recommend using async "all the way down" and [not blocking on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

The following Windows Forms code sample deadlocks as well, by way of example:

```
private async Task<bool> TryThis()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Starting TryThis");
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("In TryThis task");
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                // This runs successfully - the loop runs to completion
                Trace.TraceInformation("For loop " + i);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        });

        // This never happens due to the deadlock
        Trace.TraceInformation("About to return");
        return true;
    }

    // Button click event handler
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool result = TryThis().Result;
        // Never actually gets here
        Trace.TraceInformation("Done with result");
    }
```

To address my understanding of your broader question, async/await can be used in one of two ways: to do work asynchronously on a single thread or as an easier way to do work on a background thread. Typically you'd use the first for I/O bound tasks (there's no point in creating a thread just to wait for a result) and the second for CPU-bound tasks.

In short, these constructs are only useful if it allows the program to do more work in the same amount of time than it would have otherwise. For example, something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
     // This is a terrible thing to do but it's for illustration purposes
     Task task = Method1();
     task.Wait();

     // Some other work
 }

 private static async Task Method1() {
     await Method2();
     // Some other work
 }

 private static async Task Method2() {
     await Method3();
     // Some other work
 }

 private static async Task Method3() {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
 }
```

then you're essentially just running these sequentially (i.e. using async doesn't allow the computer to do more work than it would've been able to do otherwise), so in this case there's little point.

**Edit:** In non-console-apps, of course, a similar code sample may still have a purpose. For example, from the comments, in a web server async/await could free up the thread to do other work. Either way, the point is that async/await is useful if, and **only** if, it allows the computer to accomplish more than it would've been able to accomplish otherwise; in this particular example it doesn't.

Comment: "deadlock in several environments" several environments = any environment with synchronizationcontext != null

Comment: There's not "little point" in writing sequential async calls if your program runs on a server and cares about resource usage and scaling. For instance, on a web server every time you await, you free a thread which can then be used to process an unrelated request.